# Type from mscorlib not found

Tags: c#, reflection, mscorlib

There is something I cannot understand. I can't read the type reference:

```
Assembly mscorlib = Assembly.Load("mscorlib");

// it DOES exist, returns type reference:
mscorlib.GetType("System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IDefinitionAppId");

// but its parent scope doesn't exist.. returns null:
mscorlib.GetType("System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation"); 

// even though it exists, it doesn't compile
// System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IDefinitionAppId x;
```

How is this possible?

Comment: What is the error you are getting at compile time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your last line won't compile is because `IDefinitionAppId` is *internal* - not because `System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation` is a type.

Note that if `Isolation` were the name of a type, you'd have to use `GetType("System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation+IDefinitionAppId")` (note the +) as that's how nested types are represented in CLR names.

It's very simple to demonstrate this:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Assembly mscorlib = typeof(string).Assembly;
        string name = "System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IDefinitionAppId";
        Type type = mscorlib.GetType(name);

        // Prints System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation
        Console.WriteLine(type.Namespace);
    }
}
```

So `System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation` is a namespace, not a type, hence why `Assembly.GetType(...)` doesn't find it as a type.

Comment: internal... I knew I had missed something. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation is a namespace, not a type, you can't get a "reference" to a namespace, it's just part of the full class name.

Comment: nope, IntelliSense does't see this namespace, hence I cannot reach the nested type IDefinitionAppId

Comment: If it was a namespace I would be able to have a variable of type System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IDefinitionAppId, as you can see in the last line

Comment: @Marc: IDefinitionAppId isn't a nested type to start with.